# Mapkit, MKDirections, voice narration,

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit

I am working on an iOS 7 app that uses mapkit, and I can route and pot directions for users. 
I am trying to recreate the exact same way the apple maps app works when starting a trip, with the voice coming up and narrating the steps, and the camera movements. I don;t know whether thats possible and where can I find classes that expose that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About the narrating, I don't know. But for the traking of the user, and the camera movements, I used this library: https://github.com/100grams/CoreLocationUtils

There is a lot of helpers, I'm sure it could help you ;)

To rotate the view, you have to start the heading, like this:

```
// some code
[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
// some code
```

Then, implement this delegate method:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {

    if (newHeading.headingAccuracy > 0 && abs(self.over-newHeading.trueHeading) > 3) {

        CGFloat north = -1.0f * M_PI * (newHeading.trueHeading) / 180.0f;
        CGFloat bearing = -1.0f * M_PI * (newHeading.trueHeading-self.bearing) / 180.0f;

        /* do some verifications here
           you can make the rotation here using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(north)
           or CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(bearing )
         */

        self.over = newHeading.trueHeading;
    }
}
```

Finaly, in this delegate method, you can get the bearing value between 2 coordinates using the library (previously mentionned):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    self.currentUserLocation = newLocation;

    // set the target location...

    self.bearing = [CLLocation directionFromCoordinate:self.currentUserLocation.coordinate toCoordinate:self.targetLocation.coordinate];

}
```

Hope that will help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

This features private to Apple Maps App.
You can just use maps or create this features by yourself.

Comment: is this for sure? they do not expose any API to allow me to recreate the routing?

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenEars for a narration option.

In iOS 7 and above, `MKMapCamera` and its animation ability will help you greatly with the actual stepping through on your map view.